# Getting the rowHeight from the NSIndexPath selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way of getting the height for a row from the NSIndexPath selected?  I don't want to set the row height through the delegate methods, but if I had a table of different row heights, and wanted to get the height of the row the user touched (or in my case pinched), how do I do that?  This is what I thought would work, but it does not.

```
- (CGFloat)heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath && indexPath.section != NSNotFound && indexPath.row != NSNotFound) {
        //NSUInteger rowTouched = [indexPath row];
        //NSLog(@"%@", rowTouched);
        //NSLog(@"%@", [indexPath description]);
        return indexPath.accessibilityFrame.size.height;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I print the indexPath.accessibilityFrame.size.height, I get null.  I tried to get the row by NSLog() to the row, but I get a crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS which I'm not sure why.  When I print the description of the indexPath, I get the memory where this is at and then [0,9].  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSIndexPath` doesn't have `accessibilityFrame` property as it is not a `UIView` object. THe index path and cell are not the same thing even though they are related. You should probably get the `cell` using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the `UITableView` and then pass its frame height.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to solve here?

This is not how it works - you need to implement the delegate method to tell the framework about the height of your cells. This is how you get it. If you need the height later yourself anywhere else, feel free to call that method yourself.